# How to replace multiple string with PHP?

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have some texts below:

```
$text ='Some texts![desciptions 01][1]some texts![desciptions 02][2]Some texts [1]: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/image_F-2_at_Guam_%28Cropped%29.jpg [2]: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/image_F-2_at_Guam_%28Cropped%29.jpg
```

I want prelaces format `![desciptions 01][1]` to space, remove format `[1]: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/image_F-2_at_Guam_%28Cropped%29.jpg`'

Text format like that is there may be more than in content text, and i want to replace all by PHP.

My result like this

```
$text = 'Some texts some texts Some texts'
```

How to do that?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to replace always is the same (Static and in other words predictable), you should use the php function str_replace ([php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php))

**Example:**

```
str_replace("![desciptions 01][2]"," ",$text);
```

If what you want to replace is variable, you need a script to search for patterns. It's called regular expression search and replace ([php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)) and looks like this:

```
$patterns[] = "/\[b\]([^\n\r]*?)\[\/b\]/si";
$replacements[] = "<b>\\1</b>";
$str = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $str);

This will make [b]text[/b] into <b>text</b>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i want to replace all format include `[1]: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/image_F-2_at_Guam_%28Cropped%29.jpg`... automatically.

Comment: well, if it's always the same, you can use th str_replace(); like: `$a= "[1]: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/image_F-2_at_Guam_%28Cropped%‌​29.jpg"; str_replace($a, "", $text);`